# java.io.FileNotFoundException (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) while starting Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, ioexception

while starting jboss I am getting below error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\workspace4.3.2\workspacePLE.metadata.plugins\org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core\JBoss_AS_4.21507285539456\deploy\LocalDeploy.ear\ple.war\WEB-INF\lib\ple-data.jar!\data\config\HTMLEntities.res (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

```
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at com.inetpsa.ple.utilitaires.PleCharEntities.initialize(PleCharEntities.java:37)
    at com.inetpsa.ple.initialisation.OUInit.initHtmlEntities(OUInit.java:340)
    at com.inetpsa.ple.initialisation.OUInit.interneInit(OUInit.java:367)
    at com.inetpsa.ple.initialisation.OUInit.reinit(OUInit.java:424)
    at com.inetpsa.ple.initialisation.OUInit.init(OUInit.java:412)
```

But the file is present at this location (however it is inside a jar).

The code for getting file path is:

```
String htmlEntFileName = OUInit.class.getClassLoader().getResource("data/config/HTMLEntities.res").getPath();
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Do not use this kind of path. Use the `URL` instead...

Comment: lib!\ple-data.jar!\data\config\HTMLEntities.res ??

Can you post your question correctly, It's not clear

Answer (score 1):

You are using `FileInputStream`so I assume you ase the path to create new `FileInputStream`, but once the file is inside a jar it can't be accessed as a file anymore.

The file can be accessed as an `InputStream` using either `Class.getResourceAsStream()` or `Class.getResource().openStream()`.